# Add Column to Temp Table - 'Invalid column name DECIMAL'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm creating a temporary table via a `SELECT INTO`. I'd like to create the temp table *then* add a column to it like so:

```
 SELECT id, name, val
 INTO #TEMP_TBL

 ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TBL ADD new_col AS DECIMAL

 Error: Invalid column name 'DECIMAL'.
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Don't use the `AS`. The correct syntax is

```
 ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TBL ADD new_col DECIMAL(18,4) /*Or whatever precision/scale */
```

Or you could do this all in one go with

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       val,
       CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL(18, 4)) AS new_col
INTO   #TEMP_TBL 
FROM ....
```

It thinks you are trying to add a computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TBL(X INT)

/* Y is a computed column with same value as X*/
ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TBL ADD Y AS X
```

Comment: Care to try your hand at this one... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339995/why-is-my-alter-table-statement-not-properly-adding-a-column)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TBL ADD new_col DECIMAL
```