# Why is my alter table statement not properly adding a column to my temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, ddl, alter-table

I have a temporary table created at the beginning of this stored procedure. It is created successfully and can be selected from and inserted to.

Here is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpImportData (GuideFirstName VARCHAR(MAX), GuideLastName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                             email VARCHAR(MAX), group_id_text VARCHAR(MAX), CandidateName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                             grade_text VARCHAR(5), dateofbirth DATE

                             )
```

My problem is trying to update a column after I alter the temporary table. I get the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1
>   invalid column name

Code:

```
declare @SQl1 nvarchar(max)
set @SQL1 ='
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD group_id INT
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD guide_id INT
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD password_plain_text VARCHAR(500)
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD guide_email VARCHAR(500)
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD class_id INT'

exec sp_executesql @Sql1

UPDATE #tmpImportData 
SET group_id = CAST(group_id_text AS INT)

UPDATE #tmpImportData 
SET group_id = 0 WHERE group_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Where this 'group_id_text' came from??

Comment: Show us the `#tmpImportData` table definition (create statement). I guess you have not defined such column -.`group_id_text`

Comment: @PareshJv I have added the create statement

Comment: @gotqn I have added the create statement

Comment: @CodeFlava I am executing your code without an error on in `SQL Server Management Studio 2012`. What is your `SQL` version?

Comment: I didn't know SQL had versions? If you mean which version of SSMS am I running? It's 2012 with SP1 @gotqn

Comment: @CodeFlava is this the whole error text?

Comment: There is no error here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/23325

Answer (score 0):

try do it like this

```
declare @SQl1 nvarchar(max)
set @SQL1 ='
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD ['+@group_id+'] INT
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD ['+@guide_id+'] INT
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD ['+@password_plain_text+'] VARCHAR(500)
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD ['+@guide_email+'] VARCHAR(500)
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData 
ADD ['+@class_id+]' INT'

exec  @Sql1

UPDATE #tmpImportData 
SET group_id = CAST(group_id_text AS INT)

UPDATE #tmpImportData 
SET group_id = 0 WHERE group_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Because the variables were never declared